# UK Tourism Visa from USA, with US visa expiring in 2 months

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, h1b-visas

I want to apply for a 6-month tourist visa to the UK. I live in the US on the H1-B visa. My H1-B visa expires in January 2020.

I will renew my H-1B in January, but need to get the UK visa before that.

I know Schengen countries require my US visa be valid for 6months before I can apply for a Schengen visa. Is that true for a UK visa as well?

Answer (score 1):

The UK has no such requirement, but they are fully aware of how US visas work, so they will know that you need to have a new US visa stamped if you leave the US after your visa expires. If you have your I-797 you can submit that to prove you expect to return to the US (and thus, not overstay in the UK).